# Will JVM only pick up .jar files?

Tags: java, jar, jvm

When I give the `-classpath` argument to `java` to start will it pick up only files which have `.jar` extensions or will it attempt to look into other files in `-classpath` path as well?

Meaning if I specify `-classpath` to be `/mypath` which contains

```
/mypath/IAmANormalJar.jar
/mypath/IAmAJarWithoutExtension
```

where `IAmAJarWithoutExtension` is an actual jar file but without the `.jar` extension. Will only `/mypath/IAmANormalJar.jar` be loaded by JVM or will `/mypath/IAmAJarWithoutExtension` be loaded as well?

Comment: If your class path is `/mypath`, neither of these files will be picked up. In that case `/mypath` will be picked up. That’s different to specifying `/mypath/*` as class path. But…if you are going to specify `/mypath/*` as class path, why not `/mypath/*.jar` making your question obsolete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html

> Classpath entries that are neither directories nor archives (.zip or
>   .jar files) nor * are ignored.

The wildcard symbol explained:

> Class path entries can contain the basename wildcard character *,
>   which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files
>   in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. For example, the
>   class path entry foo/* specifies all JAR files in the directory named
>   foo. A classpath entry consisting simply of * expands to a list of all
>   the jar files in the current directory. Files will be considered
>   regardless of whether or not they are hidden (that is, have names
>   beginning with '.').

Answer (score 1):

Java classpath requires jar to be completed specified with extension. Without the extension Java treats that as a directory to which there are class files present to be added to the Java classpath. The Wikipedia article on the Java classpath provides some good information in this regard:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)

Answer (score 0):

It will only pick up files with the extension .class, .jar or .zip.  One trick I used to use when I wanted to flip between two jars for testing would be to add another extension to the file I wanted to be "out".  If the version I wanted to test was mylib.jar, I would modify the old one as mylib.jar.old and they could co-exist in the directory.